# How to Get All Posts with any post status?

Tags: query-posts, wp-query, post-status

I am creating a front end dashboard where I need to show all the posts by the current user. So, I need to show posts in all states, mainly `published`, `trashed` and the `pending`. I am now using a simple query but it is returning only the published posts.

```
$query = array(
    'post_type' => 'my-post-type',
    'post_author' => $current_user->ID              
    );
    query_posts($query);
```

Can anyone help? What else do I need to do?

Comment: Have you tried using the [`post_status` parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Type_.26_Status_Parameters), ie. `'post_status' => 'any'`?

Comment: I ***strongly*** recommend using `WP_Query` `pre_get_posts` or `get_posts` instead of `query_posts`. Never use `query_posts`

Comment: @TomJNowell: that was way back :) I use WP_Query most ofter now..

Comment: @Sisir be careful, use `WP_Query` for front-end, and `get_posts` for admin queries as there is an issue with `wp_reset_postdata` (see the [note](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Interacting_with_WP_Query) and [ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18408) on this issue).

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You can use the post_status parameter:

```
* 'publish' - a published post or page
* 'pending' - post is pending review
* 'draft' - a post in draft status
* 'auto-draft' - a newly created post, with no content
* 'future' - a post to publish in the future
* 'private' - not visible to users who are not logged in
* 'inherit' - a revision. see get_children.
* 'trash' - post is in trashbin. added with Version 2.9.
```

I'm not sure that it accepts 'any' so use an array with all of the statuses you want:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'my-post-type',
    'post_author' => $current_user->ID,
    'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending', 'draft', 'auto-draft', 'future', 'private', 'inherit', 'trash')    
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);

while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
```

Comment: You could also use `get_post_stati()` to get all statuses, including custom ones.

Comment: A wasted opportunity to kill off a `query_posts` call...

Comment: too bad we can't do something like this `'post_status' => array( '!inherit' );` (to indicate any post_status other than inherit)

Comment: @aequalsb what about `'post_status' => array_diff(get_post_stati(), ['inherit']);`

Comment: off-topic. 'any' is a real thing actually. Docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-type-parameters

Comment: This is the wrong answer. `any` is the right answer to the question `How to Get All Posts with any post status?`

Answer (score 24):

There is simple way, how to get all posts with any status:

```
$articles = get_posts(
 array(
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'post_status' => 'any',
  'post_type' => get_post_types('', 'names'),
 )
);
```

Now you can iterate throughout all posts:

```
foreach ($articles as $article) { 
 echo $article->ID . PHP_EOL; //...
}
```

Comment: **$posts and $post conflict with Wordpress' own variable names**. If you are using this code to put something in other than the primary (main content) div, this will overwrite what would have been shown in main. If your intention really is to completely replace the original query results, this is what you want, of course. But it's still a good idea to rename the $posts and $post variables.

Comment: @Henrik i am not intending to diminish your comment at all (your logic is sound and safe), but i consider using $post/$posts as perfectly acceptable inside a function without access to the global $post/$posts variables -- because it helps me maintain logic during development.

Comment: well.. almost - just try it vs @bainternet answer, you'll probably get a different count. it doesn't include auto-draft & trashed.

Comment: This is the right answer to the question `How to Get All Posts with any post status?`. `any` will get you ANY post type statūs.

Answer (score 8):

In most cases you can use `get_posts()` with `'any'` parameter for this:

```
$posts = get_posts(
 array(
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'post_status' => 'any',
  'post_type' => 'my-post-type',
 )
);
```

But this way you won't get posts with status `trash` and `auto-draft`. You need to provide them explicitly, like this:

```
$posts = get_posts(
 array(
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'post_status' => 'any, trash, auto-draft',
  'post_type' => 'my-post-type',
 )
);
```

Or you can use get_post_stati() function to provide all existing statuses explicitly:

```
$posts = get_posts(
 array(
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'post_status' => get_post_stati(),
  'post_type' => 'my-post-type',
 )
);
```

Answer (score 6):

The `WP_Query` class method `->query()` accepts an `any` argument for `post_status`. See [`wp_get_associated_nav_menu_items()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_get_associated_nav_menu_items/) for a proof.

The same goes for `get_posts()` (which is just a wrapper for above call).

Comment: From the WP_Query docs: _'any' - retrieves any status except those from post types with 'exclude_from_search' set to true._ (There's a typo there, they actually mean post statuses instead of post types.) This means statuses `auto-draft` and `trash` are excluded.

Comment: @Tamlyn Afaik, this is no typo. It _retrieves any status from post types_ that are publicly available. Status are just terms. They got no _public_ or _private_ property themselves. You _could_ disable a taxonomy with disabling the `query_var`... for whatever reason one would do that. Sidenote: [The plural of post status is...](http://unserkaiser.com/uncategorized/status-and-plural/).

Comment: If you trace through the code (often easier than reading the docs, I find) you can see that `WP_Query#get_posts()` calls `get_post_stati()` which filters `$wp_post_statuses` for values where `exclude_from_search` is true then it excludes posts with these [statuses](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+statuses) from the query. There's a similar process for post types when post_type is set to 'any'.

Comment: @Tamlyn After checking the contents of the `$wp_post_statuses` property, I have to admit that you're right :)

Comment: doesn't work for trash status.

Answer (score 4):

Even if you pass `any` as `post_status`, you [still will not get the post in the result](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/56691d83d2f9196193ab64f0a473c1e38eefa316/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L3022-L3056) if all of the following conditions are true:

1. A single post is being queried. An example of this would be querying by `name`, i.e. the slug.
2. The post has a post status that is not public.
3. The client does not have an active admin session, i.e. you are not currently logged in.

### Solution

Query *explicitly* for every status. For example, to query for stati which are not `trash` or `auto-draft` (it's pretty unlikely that you want those), you could do something like this:

```php
$q = new WP_Query([
    /* ... */
    'post_status' => array_values(get_post_stati(['exclude_from_search' => false])),
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't yet comment: `$args['post_status']='any';` works for 'publish' and 'draft', but not for 'trash',  I needed `$args['post_status']=array('any','trash');`

Comment: Wellcome to WPSE! :)