# Show Published and Draft posts from Logged in Author

Tags: author, draft

Hello there
that's what i'm trying to achieve:
i have a private page, where only author can access, after log in.
i want to show two columns:
1 - excerpts of the latest 8 posts published by the logged in author
2 - excerpts of the latest 8 drafts by the author

css and html are all set up for the two columns, but i can get the two contents to show (or at least i managed to get just the author sorting)

anyone could help?
thank you

Answer (score 1):

a similar question was asked before, if you [**take a look here**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13484/how-to-get-all-posts-with-any-post-status) obviously for 1 column use 'post_status' => 'published' and for the other column call 'post_status' => 'draft' and set number of posts to show to 8 for each column